# How to use random function when there is field function in mysql

Tags: mysql, random

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT `main_bid`,`main_plan` FROM `business` 
order by FIELD(`main_plan`,'Diamond','Platinum','Gold','Listed')
```

I want to display first `Diamond` values randomly then platinum values randomly and so on.

I know there is a `rand()` MySQL function  to get random results from tables.
But i don't know how to use it when there is already one  MySQL `FIELD()` function.

Sample data:

```
main_bid main_plan
------------------
   1      Diamond
   2      Diamond
   3      Diamond
   1      Platinum
   2      Platinum
   3      Platinum
   1      Gold
   2      Gold
   3      Gold
```

I need output as:

```
main_bid main_plan
------------------
   3      Diamond
   1      Diamond
   2      Diamond
   2      Platinum
   1      Platinum
   3      Platinum
   2      Gold
   1      Gold
   3      Gold
```

or

```
main_bid main_plan
------------------
   3      Diamond
   2      Diamond
   1      Diamond
   1      Platinum
   3      Platinum
   2      Platinum
   3      Gold
   2      Gold
   1      Gold
```

---

```
    SELECT `main_bid`,`main_plan` FROM `business` 
    order by FIELD(`main_plan`,'Diamond','Platinum'),rand()
```

This query is shuffling all results. i have to shuffle `Diamond` results first and then `Platinum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT main_bid, main_plan 
FROM business 
where main_plan in ('Diamond','Platinum')
order by case when main_plan = 'Diamond' then 1
              when main_plan = 'Platinum' then 2
         end,
         rand()
```

Comment: its shuffling all results... i need first diamond results randomly..and then platinum randomly...your query shuffling all main_plan

Comment: Then add example data to your question and expected output.

Comment: Please add explanation on what the code actually does, even if for some it is obvious on first sight.

Comment: can u check my question again...??

Answer (score 0):

Try this query instead of using `FIELDS()`

```
SELECT `main_bid`,`main_plan`,case  
     when main_plan = "Diamond" then "1" 
     when main_plan = "Platinum" then "2" 
     when main_plan = "Gold" then "3"
     end as plan_type  FROM `business` 
     order by plan_type,RAND()
```

Comment: your answer won't work when i there is more than 2 values in my column...But still thanks for help..

Comment: @user2530951 Please check my updated query,This may help you.I think

Comment: This has been automatically flagged as low-quality. Perhaps you should add some explanation about what your code does exactly, or your answer could be deleted by the community.